# Group (and ungroup) sheets in Apache POI

Tags: apache-poi

I have some code that generates a number of `SXSSFSheet`s in a `SXSSFWorkbook` using `myWorkbook.createSheet('sheetname');`

For some reason, some of the sheets are 'grouped': changes to a cell in one page are automatically made in the same cell of other sheets (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/group-worksheets-4e1f7747-3d63-4fd7-8a36-838b05adc0f0).

This is not the desired activity and I would like to prevent it. I have not found any documentation on how to group or ungroup sheets with POI.

Comment: "For some reason, some of the sheets are 'grouped'": Then your code must leading to this grouping "for some reasons". But we cannot know that reasons because we don't know your code.

Comment: Of course. But it would help if someone could point out how to intentionally "group" or "ungroup"  sheets in a workbook

Comment: If multiple worksheets are selected the same time, then those worksheets are "grouped" in the meaning of your linked Microsoft page. [Sheet.setSelected](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setSelected-boolean-) handles selecting of sheets in `apache poi`.

Comment: Thank you @AxelRichter, that's it. Setting multiple sheets as selected produces the "grouping" effect. I didn't see that documented.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Axel in the comment, setting multiple sheets as selected produces the "grouping" effect.